# Get a specific percentage chance of running something?

Tags: javascript

I read some threads on the site about getting percentages of running a function, but none of them guide me how to get a specific decimal percentage of running a function.

I tried something like:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 + '%'
```

However it doesn't return decimals.

What i'd like is for it to let's say, have a 0.5% / 100% chance of running `console.log("0.5%")`, is there any way to do this? Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not very clear what you try to achieve here. Do you want to have a function that will randomly run? Let's say 1% probability of running `console.log`? If this is what you want, what's the role of the decimals in the question?

Comment: Note you dont have decimals because you used `floor()` which rounds down the random number you generated

Comment: Do you just want to generate a random number that includes, say `0.6` or `12.1` and so on - single digit after the decimal point is allowed?

Comment: Or maybe you know how to make the `1%` probability but you can't create a `0.5%` one?

Comment: You're overthinking this. Math.random gives you a random number between 0 and 1. To get the "percentage", just multiply the result by 100. To limit the precision you can use either `.toFixed` or `toPrecision` like this: `(Math.random()*100).toFixed(2)` then you can concatenate `%`.

Comment: `if( Math.random() < 0.5/100) { /* code that runs 0.5% of the time */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1.

A percentage is just a fraction out of 100. Divide by 100 to get a number between 0 and 1.

So, to get a block of code that runs a certain percentage of the time, take the desired percentage, divide it by 100, and run the code if a random number is less than it.

```
if( Math.random() < 0.5/100) {
    /* code that runs 0.5% of the time */
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me! Both clean and short!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are asking for.

The percentageFromRandom is explained in my comment above.
The runWithProbability function calls a given function with a certain probability, when this function is called.

The logWithProbability uses the runWithProbability function, but with the custom console.log functionality as your answer question for.

The init function shows an example of usage of the function, by running it 30 times with 30 random probability. In most cases it would log the larger %'s as they are more likely to have the console.log function be called.

```js
//convert the random value into human readable percentage
function percentageFromRandom(value, fractionalDigits = 2){
    return (value*100).toFixed(fractionalDigits)+'%';
}

//take a function and probability of running it
//if the probability is met, call the function.
function runWithProbability(fn, probability){
  if(probability >= 1 || Math.random() < probability){
    return fn(probability);
  }
  return false;
}

//make a console log with a certain probability,
//log the percentage probability if called
function logWithProbability(probability){
    runWithProbability(()=>
    console.log(percentageFromRandom(probability))
    , probability);
}

// See console logs and their probability as
// a percentage of running.
const init = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    logWithProbability(Math.random());
  }
}

init();
```

Comment: You appear to be generating a probability, and then using that probability as a probability of running... That's not what OP wants.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Extracted from his question: `"What i'd like is for it to let's say, have a 0.5% / 100% chance of running console.log("0.5%"), is there any way to do this? Thank you very much!"` Just use: `logWithProbability(0.5/100)` and `logWithProbability(1)`. Clearly the `0.5%` and `100%` are examples. In programming, you tend to want to think about *general* cases, for example, any value other than 0.5% and 100%. Your answer doesn't even give the example of it running with the 100% chance.

Comment: @George Thank you very much! This is extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the `Math.floor(Math.random())` example is that `Math.floor()` removes all of the fractional values of a number. To get precision to a certain fixed point, multiply by the maximum whole number wanted, then adjust to a fixed decimal.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var num = 10 * Math.random();           // Max 10.000...
    
    console.log(num, num.toFixed(1) + '%')  // Fix (and round) the first decimal
}
```